# Remove Class on Second Click event (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a class on an element during a click event and then if I click anywhere else, I want that class removed. The problem is that everything is firing at the same time and causing problems. Just an FYI, I'm doing this as a mobile fix because of the way the site I'm working on is set up. Here's my code:

```
$('ul > li:has(.sub-menu) a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('li.clicked_link').on('click', function(){
        var this_link = $(this).attr('href');
        document.location.href=this_link;
    });
    $('body').on('click',function(){
        $('li.clicked_link').removeClass('clicked_link');
    });
    $(this).parent().addClass('clicked_link');
});
```

Basically, I'm adding a class to a parent when an anchor is clicked. I'm also deactivating that anchor's link. The problem is that it looks like it's firing the event and adding and removing the class immediately (I'm guessing, because nothing is happening). I figured because of the order of things this wouldn't happen but that's not the case.

Comment: It's a very bad idea to nest click events like this. What stops the clicks from always entering the first defined click function?

Comment: This is a fix for just mobile browsers. It's the only way I could think of getting it to work on the touch browser with the way the WordPress template is set up that I'm using.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have nested event handlers, every time you click a matching anchor a new event handler is added to both the LI's and the body, and you just keep piling on.

Also, the event handler on the body is always firing and removing the link as the click on the anchor bubbles up to the body, so first the event handler on the anchor fires and adds the class, then it bubbles up to the body and removes the class

```
$('ul > li:has(.sub-menu) a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).parent().addClass('clicked_link');
});

$(document).on('click',function(e){
    if ( $(e.target).closest('.clicked_link').length ) {

        window.location.href = this.href;

    } else {

        $('li.clicked_link').removeClass('clicked_link');

    }
});
```